# Unused variable clean-up

Tags: python, beginner

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm learning python.
I've defined a function for a dice roll and set it up to roll multiple.

```
def d20(num):
    rolls = 0
    for i in range(num):
        rolls += randint(1,20)
    return rolls
```

[Thonny](https://github.com/thonny/thonny) and my assistant tab gives me a warning:

```
Line 3: Unused variable 'i'
```

The code works fine but I like a clean workspace. I was wondering if there is an alternate way to write the range loop or is this just something I need to learn to deal with?

Comment: `return sum(randint(1, 20) for _ in range(num))`

Comment: I'd turn the thole thing in a `roll_dice(num, dice)` function that takes `d20` as an argument as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use an underscore _ instead of i

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) bear in mind that ["_Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)...

Comment: Specifically, you should explain why!